# FatFs async read without blocking

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide, fatfs

I am using stm32f103 and i need to read data from sd card. I am using a coroutine system ,so i don't want to block. Is there a possible way to read asyncly?

Answer (score 0):

You could read files by time sharing small blocks at each step.
For example read (1000) bytes at every 10 mili seconds at use that.
You could use double buffering for processing one part of data.